# How can i re-appear an object saved to a collection to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, object

I want to rearrange some graphs in my spreadsheet! To do so, i want to save them into a collection list, delete them from my sheet and place them with the order i want! For example, if I save a number or a string in a variant variable, using:

```vb
   Cells(1, 1).Value = my_value
```

In cell 1,1 will be placed my value! Can I do something similar with a graph object?

Comment: No you can't delete them and then replace them. Reorder, yes, you can do that.

Comment: even if they are saved in a collection? I cannot recall them to my spreadsheet directly from the collection???

Comment: That is correct. You could move them to a dummy new workbook though.

Comment: Ok man!!! Thanks amazingly very much for your quick answers!!! I asked this to avoid copy-pasting! It is a slow procedure and i hoped to be able to "set things" in lists and reappearing them wherever i want!!! Thanks a lot even if you broke my dreams!!! Hahaha!!! I am kidding of course! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Placing a chart into a collection only creates a reference to the chart on the sheet - a bit like writing a street address in your address book: deleting the chart is like knocking down the house...

Comment: To add to what @TimWilliams accurately said, you don't own the `Chart` object, Excel does: what you stored in the collection isn't a `Chart` object, it's a *reference* to one - basically a ticket that says "your chart is over there -->" ...so, if you delete the chart, you're left with a ticket that says "your chart is over there -->", that points to... nowhere (expect automation errors if you pull this object reference and try to manipulate it after deleting the chart)

Comment: I am new to vba!!! So your answers were extremely helpfull to understand the language's concept! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

When you add a number or a string into a collection, you're literally copying & storing the bytes of that number or string value in the collection.

When you add an object reference to a collection, you're not copying anything, and you're not adding any objects either; you're adding a *reference* to an object. If your code owns the object, then that reference is enough to keep the object "alive". But in the case of a `Chart`, the object belongs to Excel (you can't `New` it up yourself), so if the actual object is deleted in Excel, it can't be recovered from a now-stale object reference (it's not pointing anywhere anymore).

If you try using the stale object reference, expect an *automation error* at run-time.